# Threading methods from other classes?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

There is a method that is called continuously in my program and so I want to thread it such that the GUI doesn't freeze whilst it goes about its business.

```
Thread t = new Thread(Class2.ArrayWorkings(1, MyGlobals.variable1));
    t.start();
        int[] localVariable1 = ??// I want to move the value returned from the method into localVariable1.
```

Currently my errors are:

The best overloaded method match for 'System.Threading.Thread.Thread(System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart)' has some invalid arguments

&

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart'

Currently doing this without threading like:

```
   int[] localVariabl1 = Class2.ArrayWorkings(1, MyGlobals.variable1);
```

Comment: How would you expect to do that when the method hasn't finished executing yet? (Your immediate error is due to the way you're creating the thread, and the fact that you don't close the constructor call doesn't help, either...)

Comment: Which framework? Winform? WPF/SilverLight?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can fix the constructor by using a lambda:

```
Thread t = new Thread(() => Class2.ArrayWorkings(1, MyGlobals.variable1));
```

but that doesn't let you (as Jon notes) get the result straight away - otherwise you are writing synchronous code again. You can instead look to some kind of *callback*; presumably you need to get back to the UI thread, so:

```
Thread t = new Thread(() => {
    // this runs on the worker
    int[] localVariabl1 = Class2.ArrayWorkings(1, MyGlobals.variable1);
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
        // now we're back on the UI thread!
        update the UI from localVariabl1
    });
});
t.Start()
```

I would probably suggest using the thread-pool, though:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate {
    // this runs on the worker
    int[] localVariabl1 = Class2.ArrayWorkings(1, MyGlobals.variable1);
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
        // now we're back on the UI thread!
        update the UI from localVariabl1
    });
});
```

Comment: I then go onto use the locla variable in for loops so get the "does not exist in current context" error for the variable, should I make these global or something if using threading?

Comment: @user1166981 would need to see an example; in what I've posted, the variable **is** available to the UI callback code, it is a "captured variable". And no: don't make it global

Comment: I am actually using the variable to draw using DirectX and nothing else is happening in the form until the method is finished. This is all happening inside the onpaint event, where all of my display logic is (vertex calculations) and where I call the intensive method- could this be part of my problem?

Comment: @user1166981 in the case of OnPaint, you need the info synchronously, so yes: a UI callback won't help *at all*. You should have mentioned this was painting! The absolute most you can do with threading here is: if your calculations can be parallelized, to run them on multiple cores at once. But you'll need to block on those completing. If you only have one method to call, you can't do much. If you have multiple calculations / calls, maybe some Parallel.ForEach etc

Comment: I was thinking maybe I could have a looping thread calling the method from outside the onpaint event, then just periodically use the variable by calling it from inside the onpaint event, then would threading be useful?

Comment: from your last comment it seems that the code where you are trying to call thread is inherently synchronous unless you are making multiple calls to calculate vertex (whatever that is). in later case you can use multiple threads and calculate chunks of vertices.

Comment: @user1166981 very hard to say; threading is very contextual, and we don't have the context. Your question doesn't say anything about any of this.

Comment: Yes currently I call the method from within onpaintevent (not sure if its necessary to have it there) 200 times in a for loop. (it is readingprocessmemory, 200 pointers read each time (different pointers as in the for loop I use an 'i' iteration on each call to a different address.  currently it takes about 5 seconds for it all to finish, and the program freezes during that time which is annoying because it is drawing to a clickthrough transparent form which makes it not clickthrough anymore if you know what I mean due to freezing.

Comment: ok well thank you for your help, I haven't solved the problem but I think I have to change the design structure of my program to achieve what I want, I will read up on your suggestions. Your answer is the fullest with the most upvotes, so I will mark it as answered as it does answer the actual question posed despite my omitting crucial details of my particular program.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it is as following:

```
ThreadStart starter = delegate { Class2.ArrayWorkings(1, MyGlobals.variable1); };
var thread = new Thread(starter);
thread.Start();
```

Edit: Just saw that you also want to capture the return value from the thread.
You may have to use ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem as mentioned in Marc's answer

Something you might want to look at is .NET Framework 4.5 (still in Release Candidate)
Makes life easier with Asynchronous programming.

[await operator in .NET 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: from that how do you retrieve the returned value?

Answer (score 2):

You gotto put a **ThreadStart** Delegate.  If you really dont want UI to get affected, u should use **BackgroundWorker** Class.

Comment: there's nothing particularly magical about `BackgroundWorker`. If it helps, fine, but there's nothing "u should use" about it.

Comment: Yes. u can handle without background worker. for that u have to do lot of things yourself. It is easier method and also have good control over it.

Comment: meh, one single call to `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke`... frankly, `BackgroundWorker` is more work

Answer (score 1):

Tasks provide an easy interface for performing an asynchronous job that will eventually return a value. A `Task<string>` for example is a task that (eventually) returns a string where a `Task<int[]>` will return an array of integers.

```
int[] localVariable1;

// start the task
Task<int[]> myTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<int[]>(() => Class2.ArrayWorkings(1, MyGlobals.Variable1);

// when it is finished get the result and place in local variable
myTask.OnCompleted(task => localVariable1 = task.Result;);
```

If you want to update a UI compontent once the asynchronous operation is finished, you will have to use Invoke (for winforms). This allows you to work with objects that live on the UI thread (such as buttons and labels).

```
myTask.OnCompleted(task => localVariable1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    localVariable1.Value = task.Result; )));
```

Comment: hi, I am actually not making use of any of the winforms stuff, it is a directx control that I update via the onpaint event.  The method is being called from within the onpaint event too, and then after its finished I use it to calcualte the vertix math and begin scene/end scene.